# Pipeline Agent Job fails Copy Files Task

Tags: azure-devops

My Pipeline is setup to run on a few branches and whenever code gets committed, it runs to copy the files to the dev web server. The task didn't used to fail this much but it seems that we have a ton of files (~30k) as it normally runs for 15-20 mins when it succeeds.

Because the task is assigned to the job in the stages of the pipeline, I can't add the retryCount option identified by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) as you can't modify the YAML code and can only use the DevOps web interface and that option is not displayed. Considering that we use UNC target paths on a remote host, it seems like a no brainer to add the retryCount variable to the task, but how can I achieve this if DevOps won't let me...

[image: Agent Job Copy File Task]

The error I get is `Failed cp: cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=UNKNOWN)` and happens at random files every time.

I tried adding both available agents in the **agent job execution** to ease the workload but still getting the same instability. And now getting mkdir errors so I will revert this change.
[image: Agent Job Execution]

Basically all I can do is redeploy until it eventually succeeds. I can confirm that the files are not locked by other users or the web service.

The Agent Version we have is 2.196.2. on Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in my Copy file task in **Azure DevOps service**, there is a Retry count to copy the file. Also for the task in Azure DevOps service, there is a Automatic retries for a task. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#number-of-retries-if-task-failed-1.

[image]

Are you using the **Azure DevOps server**? It seems it is not supported in Azure DevOps server currently from the doc for Azure DevOps server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=classic.

You can try to request a feature for Azure DevOps Server (TFS) [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion).

Comment: We are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1 I couldn't see where it mentioned the lack of support for the server version in the links you provided. 

You would think it would be mentioned on the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) page, but no.

I do know some other features are not available on the server version compared to the cloud/service version and will accept your answer. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for anyone reading this down the line.

Due to the large amount of files being copied and the copy file tasks seem to fail at random, I would only recommend using copy files for small jobs. Instead I used the Archive and Extract tasks and that seems to have done the trick. No failures at random and runs much faster.

[image: Devops Tasks]

So in the pipeline I have the **Archive Files** task and the **Publish Build Artifacts** task. And in the release I have the **Extract Files** task.